# Unable to declare an array in UpStart but can in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh, upstart

This is a sample of a problem I'm having - trying to declare an array in Upstart. I can run the declare line on the bash prompt but when done via an upstart script - it fails silently.

```
description "bla"
author "yea"
start on runlevel [2345]
script
    echo "yo" >> /var/log/arr.log 2>&1
    declare -a MYARR=("1,2" "3,4")

    echo "stuff"
end script
```

I'm doing this on ubuntu 14.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script code will be executed using /bin/sh. Arrays won't work in pure bourne shell.

Take a look at [How to use array in sh shell](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-use-array-in-sh-shell-644142/).